# `this.files = []` throws type error locally but perform properly with online demo example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I encounter `The provided value is not of type 'FileList'` error,
when employing [cropbox](https://github.com/hongkhanh/cropbox) in my project,

The error was caused by attempting to change the `read-only` FileList

```
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
this.files = [];
getImg();
```

[image]

So I have to comment `this.files = [];` out,

However, what puzzle me is that `this.files = [];` works properly in [demo example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/t8bdodvj)

I want to learn from the error and read materials about FileList and FileReader, but still with no suffice context to understand why  `this.files = [];` perform without error in demo example,

How to understand it?

Comment: It throws the same way in your *demo example*.

Comment: I appreciate your comment very much, it's not easy for a beginner in JS to convince himself there's bug in libs. @Kaiido

Comment: Does this code come from your lib? Ps: if the intent was to clear the FileList of the `input[type="file"]`, then you'd have to set its `.value` property to `null`.

Comment: Got it. Could you please transmit the comment to answer for further reference. I transplant the codes from [hongkhanh/cropbox](https://github.com/hongkhanh/cropbox) @Kaiido

Comment: You might want to [let them know](https://github.com/hongkhanh/cropbox/issues) their example contains this typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws the same way in your demo example.
Indeed, your library's example has a *typo*... <sub>(That would raise a flag in my mind to not go see deeper how the core is written).</sub>

Since quite recently*, `input[type="file"]` can be set by scripts, while previously it required the user to pick a File. <sub>*(even though webkit-based browsers did implement this feature a long time ago)</sub>

But the value to which it is set must be a FileList, which you can currently retrieve only from an other `input[type="file"]` or from a DataTransfer object (e.g one passed through the drop event).

An Array is not a FileList, be it empty or full of Files, it won't pass the type check and will throw the error you got.

---

But, it sounds like the intent of the author here was to clear the `input[type=file]`'s FileList (probably for it to show the "Pick a File" message again (?)).
To do this, it's not the `.files` property that you should modify, but the `.value` one, and you'll set it to `null`.

```js
alwaysempty.onchange = function() {
  console.log('temporarily holds', this.files[0].name);
  console.log('___clearing___');
  this.value = null;
  console.log('currently holds %s file(s)', this.files.length);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="alwaysempty">
```